# ¿Cómo hacer un temporizador en Javascript de 60 segundos a 0, pero que siga trabajando si entra un alert o un prompt?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

Explico qué es lo que necesito, lo que he intentado y no logro conseguir con los métodos de JavaScript. Tengo que hacer un temporizador para un juego en JS. El tiempo debe empezar a correr hacia atrás cuando el juego comienza, y cada pregunta del juego la tengo que mostrar por alert, cuando el tiempo llega a 0, pues se finaliza el juego. El problema es que creo que al utilizar el alert (sucede lo mismo con un prompt o un confirm) el temporizador no actúa, y solo lo hace al finalizar la app mostrándome por consola la cuenta regresiva, cuando en realidad lo que necesito es que trabaje desde el comienzo del juego, lógicamente. He intentado hacer el temporizador con setInterval y no funciona. Espero que alguien me pueda arrojar un poco de luz sobre este asunto. Muchas gracias.

```
  const timer = () => {
  secondsTime = 30;
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(secondsTime);
    secondsTime--;
    if (secondsTime === 0) {
      console.log(`El tiempo se ha acabado`)
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, 1000);
  };

  timer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es tomar en cuenta el tiempo inicial y luego en un `setInterval` revisar cuanto tiempo ha pasado desde entonces:

```js
const end = Date.now() + 60*1000; //Aqui tomamos el tiempo de cuando queremos que el contador termine (En 60 segundos a partir de ahora)

function mostrarTiempoTranscurrido() {
  const tiempoTranscurrido = Math.floor((end - Date.now()) / 1000);
  if(tiempoTranscurrido > 0)
  {
     console.log(`Han transcurrido ${tiempoTranscurrido} segundos`);
     //Programamos para que se revise de nuevo el tiempo transcurrido en 500ms
     setTimeout(mostrarTiempoTranscurrido, 500);
  } //else: Sino no programamos nada, es como si detuvieramos el timer
}

setTimeout(mostrarTiempoTranscurrido, 500); //Mostramos el tiempo transcurrido (en este caso por consola, pero podría ser en cualquier lado)
setTimeout(() => alert("Hola mundo"), 4000); //Sacamos un alert a los 4 segundos para interrumpir el conteo
```

Ahora, una vez se cierra el `alert`, te puedes dar cuenta que el tiempo sigue "corriendo" por debajo... según cuanto te demores en cerrar el `alert`

Comment: Hola Pipe, exacto, como tu dices el temporizador sigue corriendo; tengo que conseguir de alguna manera que se detenga el temporizador. Estoy probando alguna manera de al menos el console se elimine y no se vea al llegar a 0. Es un parche, pero no tiene que estar el temporizador luego de que llegue a 0. Muchas gracias Pipe

Comment: Acabo de hacer una modificacion para que cuente de 60 hacia atrás... y pare el contador cuando llegue a cero

Comment: Excelente Pipe! Como siempre, la marqué como respuesta aceptada!! Me quedó más claro como hacerlo para otra vez! Thanks!! ;)